# Make a DataFrame with the best values from a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of DataFrames. Each of these DataFrames looks like this :

```
df_list[0] =

       place place2 value1 value2
    0   x     a     10     0
    1   y     a     15     10
    2   z     b     5      10
```

To give you a concrete example I will show two more :

```
df_list[1] =     

       place place2 value1 value2
    0   x     a     20     20
    1   y     a     0      0

df_list[2]=

       place place2 value1 value2
    0   x     a     50     10
    1   y     a     30     20
    2   z     b     0      40
```

As you can see, not each of these dataframes contains every 'place' possible. However, 'place2' is always associated to the same 'place'.

I would like to have a final DataFrame where I could see the top 3 'value1' and 'value2' and their associated "i" as in `df_list[i]`, for each 'place'. The format really doesn't matter, but for example it could look like this :

```
   place place2 v1_1st v1_1st_i v2_1st v2_1st_i v1_2nd v1_2nd_i v2_2nd v2_2nd_i v1_3rd v1_3rd_i ...
   x     a      50     2         20.    1       20.     1.      10.     0.       10.    2
   y     a      30     2         20.    2.      15.     0.      10.     0.       0.     1
   z     b      5      0         40.    2.      0.      2.      10.     0.       NaN.   NaN
```

Thank you for bearing with me ! xoxo

Comment: you shoud give your trail code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a few steps here.

First we concatenate all dfs from `df_list` while adding a column to each that keeps track of the index of that df in the list, we put it into column `di`:

```
df_ag = pd.concat([d.assign(di = n) for n,d in enumerate(df_list)], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df_ag
```

produces

```
    place    place2      value1    value2    di
--  -------  --------  --------  --------  ----
 0  x        a               10         0     0
 1  y        a               15        10     0
 2  z        b                5        10     0
 3  x        a               20        20     1
 4  y        a                0         0     1
 5  x        a               50        10     2
 6  y        a               30        20     2
 7  z        b                0        40     2
```

We will treat `value1` and `value2` separately. For value1, we groupby on `['place', 'place2']`, find 3 largest per group, and rank them (via `reset_index()` within each group)

```
df_agv1 = df_ag.groupby(['place','place2']).apply(lambda d: d.nlargest(3, 'value1').reset_index(drop=True))
df_agv1
```

this produces

```
                place   place2  value1  value2  di
place   place2                      
x       a   0   x       a       50      10      2
            1   x       a       20      20      1
            2   x       a       10      0       0
y       a   0   y       a       30      20      2
            1   y       a       15      10      0
            2   y       a       0       0       1
z       b   0   z       b       5       10      0
            1   z       b       0       40      2
```

This already has the info we need (columns `value1` and `di`). Assuming you want the format closer to the format you specified, we need to extract value1 and di for each group. We can do it like so:

```
df_agv1 = df_agv1.drop(columns = ['place','place2','value2']).unstack(level=2)
df_agv1.columns = df_agv1.columns.to_flat_index()
df_agv1
```

which produces

```
              ('value1', 0)    ('value1', 1)    ('value1', 2)    ('di', 0)    ('di', 1)    ('di', 2)
----------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  -----------  -----------  -----------
('x', 'a')               50               20               10            2            1            0
('y', 'a')               30               15                0            2            0            1
('z', 'b')                5                0              nan            0            2          nan
```

and this is what you asked for for value1. You may want to rename column labels if you do not like these

Then we can do the same for `value2` by changing value1<-->value2 in the commands above, to produce `df_agv2`, I do not repeat the steps here

If you want to put the two together you can do with something like

```
pd.concat([df_agv1,df_agv2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['x', 'a', 10, 0], ['y', 'a', 15, 10], ['z', 'b', 5, 10]], columns=['place', 'place2', 'value', 'value2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['x', 'a', 20, 20], ['y', 'a', 0, 0]], columns=['place', 'place2', 'value', 'value2'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['x', 'a', 50, 10], ['y', 'a', 30, 20], ['z', 'b', 0, 40]], columns=['place', 'place2', 'value', 'value2'])

df_list =[df1, df2, df3]
```

Identify list position for for each dataframe in list:

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df['listposition'] = i
```

Concatenate the dataframes:

```
df_temp = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

analyze for value and value2 separately but in the same way to merge later:

```
df_pv1 = df_temp[['place','place2','value', 'listposition']].sort_values('value')
df_pv1.rename(columns={'listposition': 'listposition'}, inplace=True)
df_pv2 = df_temp[['place','place2', 'value2', 'listposition']].sort_values('value2')
df_pv2.rename(columns={'listposition': 'listposition2'}, inplace=True)
```

group by place, place2 (taking head as we sorted the value columns descending)

```
df_ranked_pv1 = df_pv1.groupby(['place','place2']).head(3).sort_values(['place', 'place2', 'value'], ascending=[True, True, False])
df_ranked_pv2 = df_pv2.groupby(['place','place2']).head(3).sort_values(['place', 'place2', 'value2'], ascending=[True, True, False])
```

Put it all together. You mentioned format wasn't settled, so this is a different layout.

```
df_final = pd.concat([df_ranked_pv1, df_ranked_pv2[['value2', 'listposition2']]], axis=1)

In [125]: df_final
Out[125]:
  place place2  value  listposition  value2  listposition2
0     x      a     50             2      20              1
0     x      a     20             1      10              2
0     x      a     10             0       0              0
1     y      a     30             2      20              2
1     y      a     15             0      10              0
1     y      a      0             1       0              1
2     z      b      5             0      40              2
2     z      b      0             2      10              0
```